# Pass ForeignKey to page and retrieve data

Tags: django

I have a page that basically displays user-entered data based on a project. The initial page contains just a handful of fields one being the `project_name`, which I have set as `unique`

`project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)`

From this page, I want to open up another page based on the `project_name` which enables additional details to be added and stored in a different model.

**Models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):

    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    project_website = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    project_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ckeditor_classic = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)


class Fundamentals(models.Model):

    project_name = models.ForeignKey(Project, to_field='project_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_website = models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    project_roadmap = models.CharField(max_length=25)
 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)
```

What I am struggling to do is load the second page but displaying the `project_name` and be able to associate the next set of data to the `project`

I think i need to do this via the `views` and `urls` but I can't get it to work.

View.py

```
@login_required
def AddFundamentals(request,project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    form = AddFundamentalsForm(request.POST or None, instance=project)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('dahsboard.html')
    return render(request, 'pages/critical_fundementals.html', {'project': project, "form": form})
```

The error returned is
`AddFundamentals() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'`

but I am passing this in via the URL

`path('fundamentals/<project_id>', view=AddFundamentals, name="add_fundamentals"),`

Do I need to do more in the view to return the data based on the PK? I'm really struggling with this :(

Update: Added Forms.PY and Link

```
class AddFundamentalsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddFundamentalsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Fundamentals
        fields = '__all__'
```

`<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'add_fundamentals project.id ' %}">Critical Fundamentals</a>`

Comment: What URL are you using to access that view? Without the full context of what produced the error it's hard to understand what's causing it and whether it's something to do with your code here or just how you're trying to access it in your browser.

Comment: Can you show your `forms.py` file

Comment: Do you send the pk? For example `{% url 'add_fundamentals' project_id=object.pk %}` Also add `<int:project_id>` in the urls.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have updated my post with the forms and url.

Comment: @hills. Where do I need to add the int:project_id?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife `path('fundamentals/<int:project_id>/'`

Comment: Thanks, im now getting
Reverse for 'add_fundamentals' with keyword arguments '{'project_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['apps/fundamentals/(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: The first page now won't load, because of this link `{% url 'add_fundamentals' project_id=object.pk %}`
If i remove the link the page loads - Not sure if that helps or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Hills.

This resolved my issue `path('fundamentals/<int:project_id>/'`

I had to remove the trailing `/` and all sprung into life :)

Thanks everyone.